# If two players both have pocket aces, who wins?

Tags: starting-hand

If player 1 has As Ac and player 2 has Ah and Ad and the 5 community cards are 7c Jh 4s 8h and Qc. Who would win, player 1 or 2?

In general, if two people have the same value of pocket pairs, how is the winner decided?

Moreover, instead of having pocket aces preflop,  if player 1 gets his second Ace to form Ace pair when the river card is dealt, does it cause any change in hand ranking?

Answer (score 0):

The plot will be split between both players, as the hands they can form (As Ac Qc Js 8h **vs** Ah Ad Qc Js 8h) have equal strength. In the spot you're using (AA vs AA), the only possiblity for either player to win at showdown the entire pot is to get a flush.

There are situations in which the pot can be split among more than two players. For instance, four players may have AK (whatever flush you want) in a QQQQ3 board.

**Curious side note**: In a board like As Kc Qd Jh Ts, every player still in the hand at showdown will get his chunk of the pot.

I don't know if I understood the last situation correctly. Wouldn't player 2 get a set there?

Answer (score 0):

David already does a good job answering your question.

As for your last question. If player 1 has As x (where x is any random card, except an ace), and player 2 has Ah Ad, and the board is 7c Jh 4s 8h Ac, then player 2 will win because he hit a set. AAAJ8 vs AAxJ8

If the board is 7c Jh 4s 8h Ac, and both players for example have AK then it will also be a split pot because the best 5 cards are the same for both players: AAKJ8